# Where is the "Search" menu coming from?

Tags: chrome-for-android, google-search

On my Pixel 2 XL,  select some text in Chrome.  I get a Web Search option that uses Google.  However I also get a "Search" option that uses Bing.

I don't have any Bing apps installed.  I've got Google as my default search engine.  Where is this Bing search option coming from?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  I installed the Microsoft Edge browser.  That was inserting the menu item in Chrome.  Once I uninstalled Microsoft Edge, the menu went away.